# adding comment tag on XML file through unix

Tags: xml

INPUT XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Dcn xmlns="http://schemas.test.com/2013/ClaimRequest" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.test.com/2013/ClaimRequest gdhjf/profiles/Redirect/dhd/Desktop/dhd_Prof.XSD" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header sendingSystemId="XYC" receivingSystemId="ABC" version="2.0" createDateTime="2019-01-19T04:27:15" batchingControlNumber="AZ042018" transType="ClaimRequest" dcn="1901959351"/>
  <Body>
    <ClaimRequest>
      <Claims>
        <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180409120000102" claimEndDate="2018-04-02" claimStartDate="2018-04-02" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">
          <PayToProvider id="54321"/>
          <Patient eligSysId="dhhgs1" clientId="VBV"/>
          <ClaimLines>
            <ClaimLine sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="1" />
            <ClaimLine sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="2" />
            <ClaimLine sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="3" />
          </ClaimLines>
          <ClaimTrailer claimDetailLineCount="3"/>
        </ProfessionalClaim>
         <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000277" claimEndDate="2018-04-12" claimStartDate="2018-04-12" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">
          <PayToProvider id="54673"/>
          <Patient eligSysId="dhhgs1" clientId="VBV"/>
          <ClaimLines>
            <ClaimLine sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="1" />
          </ClaimLines>
          <ClaimTrailer claimDetailLineCount="1"/>
        </ProfessionalClaim>
        <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000279" claimEndDate="2018-04-17" claimStartDate="2018-04-17" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">
          <PayToProvider id="676543"/>
          <Patient lastName="CLARK" memberId="U1672936601" firstName="DANIEL" eligSysId="CNCIEDW1" clientId="CNC"/>
          <ClaimLines>
            <ClaimLine  sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="1" />
            <ClaimLine  sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="2" />
          </ClaimLines>
          <ClaimTrailer claimDetailLineCount="2"/>
        </ProfessionalClaim>
        <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000281" claimEndDate="2018-04-17" claimStartDate="2018-04-17" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">
          <PayToProvider id="653473"/>
          <Patient lastName="VAUGHN" memberId="U1677077501" firstName="KAREN" eligSysId="CNCIEDW1" clientId="CNC"/>
          <ClaimLines>
            <ClaimLine sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="1"/>
            <ClaimLine sourceSystemClaimLineNumber="2"/>
          </ClaimLines>
          <ClaimTrailer claimDetailLineCount="2"/>
        </ProfessionalClaim>
      </Claims>
      <IcnCount total="4"/>
    </ClaimRequest>
  </Body>
</Dcn>
```

I have to add comment tag before the header tag in this XML file with the following details populated.

```
<!-- Claims Paid_Start_Date="2018-04-02" Paid_End_Date="2018-04-17" Process_Start_Date="20180409" Process_End_Date="201804301" -->
```

Here,

- Claim_Start_Date= MINIMUM of claimsStartDate from the file.
- Claim_End_Date= MAXIMUM of claimEndDate from the file
- Process_Start_Date= First claimprocessedDateTime from the file
- Process_End_Date= Last claimProcessedDateTime from the file

This is what I have done so far:

F_LINE=`awk '/<professionalclaim/' test.xml | head -1`

L_LINE=`awk '/<professionalclaim/' test.xml | tail -1`

Now I need to pull the required values from these two lines and populate in comment tag.

Comment: Hello Velava Shanmugam. It seems there are two issues here: (1) you need to parse and process the file to get the values for the comment, (2) you need to add the comment to the file. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have just captured the first and last line that matches the string "<ProfessionalClaim " and stored them in to one variable each.  F_LINE=awk '/<ProfessionalClaim/' test.xml | head -1                                         L_LINE=awk '/<ProfessionalClaim/' test.xml | tail -1

Comment: Thanks! Its done. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Using an XML parser you can extract the necessary components one at a time like this. Let's assume your file is `x.xml`.

```
# Parse the XML file for the relevant entries
#
minClaimStartDate=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:ProfessionalClaim/@claimStartDate' -n x.xml | sort -V | head -n1)
maxClaimEndDate=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:ProfessionalClaim/@claimStartDate' -n x.xml | sort -V | tail -n1)
...

# Grab the XML declaration header
#
header=$(head -n1 x.xml)    # Ugh, I can't find a way to do this properly
```

And then you can put the pieces back together like this

```
# Output composite
#
echo "$header"
echo "<!-- Claims Paid_Start_Date="$minClaimStartDate" Paid_End_Date="$maxClaimEndDate" ... -->"
xmlstarlet fo --omit-decl x.xml
```

Comment: xmlstarlet - is this a variable? I am getting error not found.

Comment: It's a program. If you're going to parse XML then use an XML parser.

Comment: Looks like it is not there. Getting "Command not found error"

Comment: You could install it. Or ask your system administration team to do that for you.